# Pinning applications or shortcuts to the task bar using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've tried this:

```
    $shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
    $folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Windows')    
    $item = $folder.Parsename('notepad.exe')
    $verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Tas&kbar'}
    if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}
```

And this:

```
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="Target item to pin. Ex: C:\windows\notepad.exe")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Target
    )
    if (!(Test-Path $Target)) {
        Write-Warning "$Target does not exist"
        break
    }

    $KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
    $KeyPath2  = "*"
    $KeyPath3  = "shell"
    $KeyPath4  = "{:}"
    $ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
    $ValueData =
        (Get-ItemProperty `
            ("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\" + `
                "CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin")
       ).ExplorerCommandHandler

    $Key2 = (Get-Item $KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($KeyPath2, $true)
    $Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
    $Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
    $Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)

    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    $Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
    $Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
    $Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")

    $Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
    if ($Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) {
        $Key2.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath3)
    }
```

But nothing seems to be working as of MS 1903.

Does anyone have a possible solution for this?
These seemed to have worked before 1803.
I have to add more details to this because this post is mostly code.

Comment: 1803 or 1903? One of those is a typo? You can use the [edit] link below the question to correct it, and add any other relevant information you may have forgotten...

Comment: check this out - https://pinto10blog.wordpress.com/2016/09/10/pinto10/